# rails rspec email different process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rspec

I am testing email sending for my controller specs, but the tests are not able to detect that an email is being sent. I can see it in the logs, but the tests are not able to see it. My suspicion is that the tests are being executed in a different thread than the email so the tests are not able to see it. Any ideas?

Controller:

```
def update
  if @task.save!
    Emailer.send_task_email(@task.creator, :task_assigned, @task.project, @task).deliver
  end
end
```

Controller Spec:

```
it 'emails the creator' do
  john = build(:user)
  task = create(:task, :creator => john, project: project)

  put :update, { :id => task.to_param }

  Emailer.should_receive(:send_task_email).with(task.creator, :task_assigned, task.project, task)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `Emailer.should_receive` line up above your `put :update` line.  You need to tell it to expect that call before you invoke the action that will call it.

Comment: Finally the following worked for me: `let(:mail) { double("mail", :deliver => true) } and Emailer.should_receive(:send_task_email).with(task.creator, :task_assigned, task.project, task).and_return(mail)`